# Error SQL Server 2012: Parameters were not supplied for the function X

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, stored-functions

I have defined a table-valued function `X` with 11 parameters. Their types are `nvarchar(30)`, `nvarchar(30)`, `datetime`, `datetime`, `nvarchar(15)`, `nvarchar(4)`, `xml`, `nvarchar(8)`, `nvarchar(80)`, `bit`, and `bit` respectively. This is for Microsoft SQL Server 2012. When I call the function with

```
select * from 
X('A','B','2014-01-01','2014-12-31',null,null,'<C><D>E</D></C>',null,null,1,0)
```

I run into this error:

```
Parameters were not supplied for the function X
```

It is apparently different from the following two:

```
An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function X
Procedure or function X has too many arguments specified.
```

Is this related to two of the intended parameter values being `null`? How can I overcome the problem and define/call a table-valued function such as this one with 11 parameters, some of which may carry `null`?

**UPDATE** The problem remains if I pass in arbitrary strings instead of `null`. So there must be another (perhaps stupid) mistake.

Comment: Can you give the first lines of your function declaration for X?

Comment: I have defined a tvf like the one you describe, and used your query  to test. It executes without any problem. There must be a problem with the definition of the function

Comment: Can you please provide you function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to define a function like the one you describe is the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION X
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @a nvarchar(30), 
    @b nvarchar(30), 
    @c datetime, 
    @d datetime, 
    @e nvarchar(15), 
    @f nvarchar(4), 
    @g xml, 
    @h nvarchar(8), 
    @i nvarchar(80), 
    @j bit,  
    @k bit   
)
RETURNS 
@output TABLE 
(
    -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
    data nvarchar(250)
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @output (data) 
    VALUES (@a + @b)    

    RETURN 
END
GO
```

Given the above definition, this:

```
select * from 
X('A','B','2014-01-01','2014-12-31',null,null,'<C><D>E</D></C>',null,null,1,0)
```

yields the following result:

```
data
----
AB
```

Comment: +1 Really a stupid mistake on my part. My table inside function `X` was called `@X` and I was using `INSERT INTO X` instead of `INSERT INTO @X`. The former (almost) looks like a recursive call and hence ...

Comment: @Drux - I just made the same mistake, this helped me find it.  That being said, the error message could be a lot clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If your function does not need any parameters, but you are still getting this error:

> Parameters were not supplied for the function

```
select * from [dbo].[myfunction]
```

Try adding () after the function call:

```
select * from [dbo].[myfunction]()
```